# Listar itens mais frequentes no banco de dados utilizando LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Gostaria de listar na tela, tipo um ranking, os itens mais frequentes na tabela do banco de dados através do nome dele, por exemplo:

João aparece 6 vezes;
José aparece 4 vezes;
Maria aparece 1 vez.

Alguem saberia me ajudar?

obs: Estou fazendo uma aplicação web utilizando asp.net mvc 5.

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
var grupos = db.Entidade
                  .GroupBy(e => e.Nome)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .ToList();
```

Cada elemento de `grupos` é uma enumeração especial (chamada de `Grouping`) que possui um atributo `Key` (neste caso, o nome da pessoa). Ou seja, para obter os registros, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
foreach (var registros in grupos) {
    Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + registros.Key);
    foreach (registro in registros)
    {
        // Aqui vai uma lógica para lidar com cada registro.
    }
}
```